# Jekyll не устанавливается

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jekyll

При попытке установить Jekyll вылазит следующее:

```
mauris_group@VGN-FW11MR:~$ gem install jekyll bundler  

Приложение 'gem' может быть найдено в следующих пакетах:
 * ruby
 * rubygems
Попробуйте: sudo apt-get install <выбранный пакет>  
mauris_group@VGN-FW11MR:~$
```

Кто знает как установить этот проклятый Jekyll?

Comment: Да, поставил последнюю версию. Ubuntu 14

Comment: mauris_group@VGN-FW11MR:~$ sudo gem install jekyll bundler
sudo: gem: command not found
mauris_group@VGN-FW11MR:~$ То есть jekyll работать не будет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала надо установить [RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/pages/download), a [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) - это уже `gem` к нему..